# gameobject clones using up too much memory

Tags: unity-game-engine

currently developing a game for school. We intended to instantiate platforms as our character lands on a platform by using collision triggers. I have been successful in triggering them, landing on them which then triggers to instantiate new platforms. My problem now is that after 9 triggers, the game lags,I feel the approach is using too much memory which is why after some time the game lags.

Is there a better approach to this?

EDIT:

```
public Transform[] spawnLocations;
public GameObject[] platform1;
public GameObject[] platformclone;
public float movespeed;
public bool moveRight;


void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D col)
{
    platformclone[0] = Instantiate(platform1[0], spawnLocations[0].transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0)) as GameObject;
    platformclone[1] = Instantiate(platform1[1], spawnLocations[1].transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0)) as GameObject;



}
```

This script is attached to the platform. We then created two empty child objects under the initial platform and prelocated them. When our character lands on the the platform, by collision trigger, the two platforms are created underneath(In the hierarchy, this is labeled as platform(clone).

a Box Collider2D is attached to the character with is trigger ticked. A box collider2D is on the platform.

When the character lands on one of the new platforms, two new platforms are then created, then the label becomes platform(clone)(clone).

the entire thing repeats itself until around the 9th-10th instance where the character will still and as their is a box collider but no platform is seen, the game at this point becomes sluggish.

Comment: so it wouldn't matter if what I'm seeing on the hierarchy tab is platform(clone)(clone)(clone)(clone)(clone)(clone)?

the game shouldn't lag?

any idea behind the lag?

Comment: Although you can instantiate many platforms, however if not all are visible at the same time, try to disable those out of sight. This is very useful to increase the FPS and lower down the batches.

Comment: how I would do that?Is it even necessary?We attached the camera to the player, so in essence, the other platforms goes off screen as the character comes down.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: check edited post @Catwood

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to develope infinite run game. If it is true you need to instantiate visible+1 perefab object and when a prefab is passed translate it to the last elements position. You need to change, not destroy and recreate your platform (i think this is prefab).

**EDIT**

I Dont check syntax error the code below is for explaining logic.

```
public Transform[] spawnLocations;
public GameObject[] platform1;
public GameObject[] platformclone;
public float movespeed;
public bool moveRight;
public List<GameObject> instantiatedPlatforms;
public int poolSize = 10;

void Start(){
    //Pool Platforms
    instantiatedPlatforms = new List<GameObject>();
    instantiatedPlatforms.Add(Instantiate(platform1[0], Vector3.zero, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0)) as GameObject);  //you can set whatever position you want this is for initialization.
    instantiatedPlatforms.Add(Instantiate(platform1[1], Vector3.zero, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0)) as GameObject);
    //If you have many platform1 objects. you can do it with loop
    //for(int i=0;i<poolSize;i++){
      // instantiatedPlatforms.Add(Instantiate(platform1[i], Vector3.zero, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0)) as GameObject);
    //}
    //after that you can set first platform prefab
     instantiatedPlatforms[0].transform.position = spawnLocations[0].transform.position;
     instantiatedPlatforms[1].transform.position = spawnLocations[1].transform.position;
}
void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D col)
{
    //platformclone[0] = Instantiate(platform1[0], spawnLocations[0].transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0)) as GameObject;
    //platformclone[1] = Instantiate(platform1[1], spawnLocations[1].transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0)) as GameObject;
    //Get usedPrefabs
    GameObject obj1 = instantiatedPlatforms[0];
    GameObject obj2 = instantiatedPlatforms[1];
    //Change Value
    obj1.transform.position = Vector3.zero;
    obj2.transform.position = Vector3.zero;
    //Change List Position (Remove First insert last)
    instantiatedPlatforms.Remove(0); //remove first and second elements
    instantiatedPlatforms.Remove(0); //after first remove second member becomes first so need 2 times remove.
    instantiatedPlatforms.Add(obj1); //set last
    instantiatedPlatforms.Add(obj2);
    //set new prefabs to spawn positions
    instantiatedPlatforms[0].transform.position = spawnLocations[0].transform.position;
    instantiatedPlatforms[1].transform.position = spawnLocations[1].transform.position;
}
```

Comment: it's platformer game actually. We decided to do this approach to have uniformity in the positioning of the prefabs. When I get past 8, the prefabs don't load anymore though I can still land on them and the game begins to  stutter at this point.

Comment: first please check [OnTriggerStay](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerStay.html) has performance problem. [OnTriggerEnter](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter.html) is good for triggering. Secondly translate prefabs position not load it. Like: `PrefabName.transform.position = newPosition;`

Comment: this is how I did it:

      void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D col)
    {
        platformclone[0] = Instantiate(platform1[0], spawnLocations[0].transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0)) as GameObject;
        platformclone[1] = Instantiate(platform1[1], spawnLocations[1].transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0)) as GameObject;
        Debug.Log("hit", gameObject);

        
    }

Comment: damn,seriously having a hard time commenting code -.-

Comment: ok you need to move unused platformclone object. When it is passed or broken etc you pass away it. after it is necessary you can change it's position to the necessary point.

Comment: how do I do that? Positions are fixed because they are attached to an empty gameobject. The script sees the gameobject and loads the platform there.

Comment: Where is your colliders? Prefabs or static position?

Comment: check edited post  with code and a bit more explanation. @Barış Çırıka

Comment: code is here if i understand your problem properly code will usefull